# How to watch on string changed - backspace added, in angular?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I'm looking workaround to catch user presses backspace (aka keytype 32) on Android. It works well in chrome but not on devices.

The one of my tries is to use simple `watch`.

However the `$watch` doesn't catch backspace pressed.

Here is what I did so far:

```
<div class='form-group'>
   <label>Field 1</label>
  <input type='text' ng-model='f1' required class="form-control">
 </div>

<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
   {{line}}
</div>
```

and:

```
  $scope.lines = [];

  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.f1;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.lines.push(newValue);
}, true);
```

This is a demo in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6w02tEtDauKUbF16E3uk?p=preview)</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

I tried `ng-change` - get the same result. When I press backspace nothing happens

Demo with ng-change <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IOpFPV3lriWjEWHgb9jJ?p=preview)</kbd>

Please help,

Comment: Have you tried `ng-change`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to check your console for errors. Basically the problem is not with backspace, but with the `ng-repeat` trying to have duplicate entries. So when you hit backspace, the array is trying to have the exact same item pushed.

Instead, use objects with the desired text:

```
$scope.lines.push({ text: newValue });
```

Also, use `ng-change` instead of `$watch`. It is there for this exact use case.

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pMyvHXDEaCSmvyM8N5GH?p=preview

---

It looks like fessy actually wants to preserve trailing spaces that are trimmed by default in angular. In that case, look at `ng-trim`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Basically setting `ng-trim="false"` inside the input declaration will disable auto trimming.

Comment: I use ng-repeat only for demo. For sure I would print it in console.

Comment: I posted the example you can grab it. It doesn't work. Watcher doesn't catch it

Comment: Thank you but in IE and Chrome example you posted doesn't work. I type "aaaa   " and it catches only "aaaa"

Comment: So you are trying to catch trailing spaces then, NOT backspace?

Comment: Updated answer for you, but you should really reword the question.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt has pointed out, this is because of dupliates in the array. Angular repeat tracks ng-repeat by an unique id. If not specified this will be taken as the repeated value as in this case line and if duplicates are there this value will be rejected.
But ng-repeat provides an option for duplicates, you can optionally provide track by some unique parameter. For your case, just replace the ng-repeat with

```
ng-repeat="line in lines track by $index"
```

Let me know if this works.

I guess the above logic works fine. [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/556i83CnjJktsG65BmM1?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, as I told to  @MattWay even if i'll print to console - nothing happens. I used `ng-repeat` only to let you see where is a problem

Comment: can you please check the plnkr link - http://plnkr.co/edit/556i83CnjJktsG65BmM1?p=preview. I have updated your code and this is working fine.